# Polars non-contiguous uniqueness filter

Tags: python-polars

## TL;DR

I'd like to be able to concisely (with performance) filter on **contiguous** row uniqueness, not **continuous** row uniqueness.

## Context

I have a LazyFrame with data already ordered correctly. While each row of the data will always be truly unique over all columns (as it's timestamped) the specific subset (columns) I am interested in can have non-contiguous duplicates, for example:

| id | data | note |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | A | new value (first time it's seen) |
| 1 | A | contiguous duplicate |
| 2 | B | new value |
| 3 | A | non-contiguous duplicate of A which I want! |
| 4 | C | new value |
| 5 | D | new value |

When using `polars.LazyFrame.unique` these two different series of `A` at `0-1` and `3` cannot be kept as unique checks for continuous (not contiguous) uniqueness. I could keep row `0` **or** row `3` and not (if using `keep='last'`) say row `1` **and** row `3`.

I have solved this for the following MRE dataset using the following code but I wonder if there's a better way. The rows with `(want)` (purely for illustration) are the ones I desire. The row ids are to help with visual-grepping of the rows, the only real discriminants here are the `foo`, `bar`, and `baz` columns.

I solved this by adding a mask value of `0` or `1` each time a row is not the same as the previous one (over the desired columns). Then cumulatively summing this mask value gives a unique value (within the mask column itself) which I can run `unique` over to keep non-contiguous duplicate values while removing the contiguous ones.

| id | foo | bar | baz | nb |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a_1 | 33 | 33 | 33 | new (want) |
| b_1 | 22 | 33 | 33 | new |
| b_2 | 22 | 33 | 33 | contig dup |
| b_3 | 22 | 33 | 33 | contig dup |
| b_4 | 22 | 33 | 33 | contig dup |
| b_5 | 22 | 33 | 33 | contig dup last (want) |
| c_1 | 22 | 33 | 22 | new |
| c_2 | 22 | 33 | 22 | contig dup |
| c_3 | 22 | 33 | 22 | contig dup |
| c_4 | 22 | 33 | 22 | contig dup |
| c_5 | 22 | 33 | 22 | contig dup last (want) |
| d_1 | 22 | 33 | 33 | new non-contig dup of b_1 etc (want) |
| e_1 | 22 | 33 | 22 | new non-contig dup of c_1 etc (want) |
| f_1 | 22 | 22 | 22 | new |
| f_2 | 22 | 22 | 22 | contig dup |
| f_3 | 22 | 22 | 22 | contig dup |
| f_4 | 22 | 22 | 22 | contig dup |
| f_5 | 22 | 22 | 22 | contig dup last (want) |
| g_1 | 11 | 11 | 11 | new |
| g_2 | 11 | 11 | 11 | contig dup |
| g_3 | 11 | 11 | 11 | contig dup |
| g_4 | 11 | 11 | 11 | contig dup |
| g_5 | 11 | 11 | 11 | contig dup last (want) |

Current solution:

```py
dirty_df = pl.scan_csv(non_contig_data)

clean_df = (
    dirty_df
    # Construct the increment mask of 0 or 1.
    .with_columns(
        (
            pl.col('foo').diff().cast(pl.Boolean) |
            pl.col('bar').diff().cast(pl.Boolean) |
            pl.col('baz').diff().cast(pl.Boolean)
        ).fill_null(True).cast(pl.Int32).alias('incr_grouping_mask')
    )
    # Cumulatively sum that mask.
    .with_columns(
        pl.col('incr_grouping_mask').cumsum()
    )
    # Run unique over the cumulative sum of the mask.
    .unique(
        maintain_order=True,
        subset='incr_grouping_mask',
        keep='last'
    )
    .collect()
)

print(clean_df)
```

Producing the correct result:

```
shape: (7, 6)
┌─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬───────────────────────────────────┬────────────────────┐
│ id  ┆ foo ┆ bar ┆ baz ┆ nb                                ┆ incr_grouping_mask │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- ┆ ---                               ┆ ---                │
│ str ┆ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ str                               ┆ i32                │
╞═════╪═════╪═════╪═════╪═══════════════════════════════════╪════════════════════╡
│ a_1 ┆ 33  ┆ 33  ┆ 33  ┆ new (want)                        ┆ 1                  │
│ b_5 ┆ 22  ┆ 33  ┆ 33  ┆ contig dup last (want)            ┆ 2                  │
│ c_5 ┆ 22  ┆ 33  ┆ 22  ┆ contig dup last (want)            ┆ 3                  │
│ d_1 ┆ 22  ┆ 33  ┆ 33  ┆ new non-contig dup of b_1 etc (w… ┆ 4                  │
│ e_1 ┆ 22  ┆ 33  ┆ 22  ┆ new non-contig dup of c_1 etc (w… ┆ 5                  │
│ f_5 ┆ 22  ┆ 22  ┆ 22  ┆ contig dup last (want)            ┆ 6                  │
│ g_5 ┆ 11  ┆ 11  ┆ 11  ┆ contig dup last (want)            ┆ 7                  │
└─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴───────────────────────────────────┴────────────────────┘
```

Answer (score 0):

I came up with two more variants one using `pl.concat_list` and the other `pl.fold`. I added a simple prefix to the columns of interest so I can regex select them.

## `pl.concat_list`

```py
clean_df = (
    df
    .with_columns(
        pl.concat_list(
            pl.col('^dp_.*$')
            .diff()
            .cast(pl.Boolean)
            .fill_null(True)
        )
            .arr
            .contains(True)
            .cast(pl.Int32)
            .alias('incr_grouping_mask')
            .cumsum()
    )
    .unique(
        maintain_order=True,
        subset='incr_grouping_mask',
        keep='last'
    )
    .collect()
)
```

## `pl.fold`

```py
clean_df = (
    df
    .with_columns(
        pl.fold(
            acc=pl.lit(False),
            function=lambda acc, x: acc | x,
            exprs=pl.col('^dp_.*$')
                .diff()
                .cast(pl.Boolean)
                .fill_null(True)
        )
            .cast(pl.Int32)
            .alias('incr_grouping_mask')
            .cumsum()
    )
    .unique(
        maintain_order=True,
        subset='incr_grouping_mask',
        keep='last'
    )
    .collect()
)
```

Comment: You may be looking for a struct: `.with_columns(incr_grouping_mask = (pl.struct(["foo", "bar", "baz"]) != pl.struct(["foo", "bar", "baz"]).shift()).cumsum())`

Answer (score 0):

From my experience with Pandas, I used to deal with these sort of things using `diff()`.

This may not be applicable in your case, depending on the data dtype, but here is what I came up with:

```
df.with_columns(
    pl.col('data').cast(pl.Categorical).cast(pl.UInt8).alias('cats'),
    pl.col('data').cast(pl.Categorical).cast(pl.UInt8).diff().alias('diff'),
    (pl.col('data').cast(pl.Categorical).cast(pl.UInt8).diff() != 0).alias('keep')
)
.filter(pl.col('keep'))
```

which produces

```
┌─────┬──────┬───────────────────────────────────┬──────┬──────┬──────┐
│ id  ┆ data ┆ note                              ┆ cats ┆ diff ┆ keep │
│ --- ┆ ---  ┆ ---                               ┆ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---  │
│ i64 ┆ str  ┆ str                               ┆ u8   ┆ i16  ┆ bool │
╞═════╪══════╪═══════════════════════════════════╪══════╪══════╪══════╡
│ 0   ┆ A    ┆ new value (first time it's seen)  ┆ 0    ┆ null ┆ true │
│ 2   ┆ B    ┆ new value                         ┆ 1    ┆ 1    ┆ true │
│ 3   ┆ A    ┆ non-contiguous duplicate of A wh… ┆ 0    ┆ -1   ┆ true │
│ 4   ┆ C    ┆ new value                         ┆ 2    ┆ 2    ┆ true │
│ 5   ┆ D    ┆ new value                         ┆ 3    ┆ 1    ┆ true │
└─────┴──────┴───────────────────────────────────┴──────┴──────┴──────┘
```

(You can remove the filter stage to make the keep values appear more clearly)

The Categorical and UInt8 casts are only there to transform Utf8 data to a numerical data type to apply diff()